# Keep current Jquery accordion pane open after postback

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

its me again.
this time i am trying to keep the current JQuery accordion pane open after postback. I have followed the example here: [Keep the current jQuery accordion pane open after ASP.NET postback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148933/keep-the-current-jquery-accordion-pane-open-after-asp-net-postback) in addition to couple others i have seen around. i still cannot get it to work, the only difference with mine is that i am formulating the script through my code behind and pushing to the client.

this is what i have:

```
    public static string getAccordionContainerScript(string container)
    {
        return @"$(document).ready(function() { var activeIndex = parseInt($('#<%=accordionActiveIndex.ClientID %>').val()); $(" + '"' + '#' + container + '"' + ").accordion({collapsible: true, heightStyle: \"content\", navigation: true,change: function (event, ui) { var index = $(this).accordion(\"option\", \"active\");$('#<%=accordionActiveIndex.ClientID %>').val(index);} }).show(); })";
    }
```

my reason for doin this is due to the fact that i am re-using code blocks as i have several of the same controls throughout the application.

also, when i use the markup display expression (<%= =>), it throws a client error and my other client controls do not work such as my modal, etc.

client error is: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #<%=accordionActiveIndex.ClientID %>

what could i be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing wrong exactly what the error message says:

You are sending to the Response the string `<%=accordionActiveIndex.ClientID %>`. That string must be processed by the WebForms engine, so it must be in the aspx page. The browser doesn't know how to deal with that code, and that's why the browser is throwing that error.

I'm afraid that you need the `accordionActiveIndex.ClientID` value passed to that function, so you can do something like this (note the new parameter, and also, ignore the line breaks in the string. I've added for legibility):

```
public static string getAccordionContainerScript(string container, string clientId)
{
    return string.Format(@"$(document).ready(function() { var activeIndex = parseInt($('#<%=accordionActiveIndex.ClientID %>').val()); 
                           $(" + '"' + '#' + container + '"' + ").accordion({collapsible: true, heightStyle: \"content\", navigation: true,change: function (event, ui) { var index = $(this).accordion(\"option\", \"active\");
                           // pay attention here
                           $('#{0}').val(index);} }).show(); }), clientId);
}
```

Comment: i still did not get it to work with your suggestion. my next bet is to manually assign the hidden field value through which ever event that is called since i would already know which pane would contain which events. that seems to work partially except that i need to work out the best place to put the assignment code as it is only updated the second time the event is fired, i think the page_load has something to do with it. thanks anyway.

Comment: i got it to work by manually assigning the panes through the different events. the reason why it did not work on the first event fire was due to the fact that the page_load was resetting the values.