# Jquery accordion retain the open pane on postback

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I am trying to retain the opened pane in accordion. This what I have in my page

```
 <div id="accordion">
    <h3>Applicant Type</h3>
    <div>                          
        some content 
    </div>
    <h3>Application Details</h3>
    <div> 
    </div>
    <h3>Current Residential Address Details</h3>
    <div>
        some content 
    </div>
    <h3>Previous Residential Address Details</h3>
    <div>
        some content 
    </div>
    <h3>Originator Details</h3>
    <div>
        some content 
    </div>  
</div> 
var leftActiveIndex = parseInt($('#<%=LeftAccordionIndex.ClientID %>').val());

 $("#accordion").accordion({
    autoHeight: false,
    event: "mousedown",
    active: leftActiveIndex,
    change: function (event, ui) {
        //var index = $(this).children('h3').index(ui.newHeader);
        var index = $(this).accordion("option", "active");
        $('input[id$=LeftAccordionIndex]').val(index);
    }
});
```

I go this from this link, 
[keep-the-current-jquery-accordion-pane-open-after-asp-net-postback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148933/keep-the-current-jquery-accordion-pane-open-after-asp-net-postback)

But this doesn't seems to be working for me.

Comment: What if you used localStorage to save which section was active?

Comment: You aren't wrapping the script into <script> tags and the Document.ready.

Comment: The value of variable leftActiveIndex is always 0. Am I missing ID attribute of this accordion to get the value on the variable?

Comment: @Wilfredo P, It's in the Document.ready script. I copied just this code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution - use an UpdatePanel.

More complex solution - use HttpHandlers instead of button click event handlers in your code-behind, that way there is no postback.