# Keep JQuery Accordion current pane open after postback in asp.net MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have jquery accordion in asp.net mvc application and I am trying to keep the current pane open after post back. I tried the solutions provided under this [Keep the current jQuery accordion pane open after ASP.NET postback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148933/keep-the-current-jquery-accordion-pane-open-after-asp-net-postback). But nothings seems to work for me.

```
<input type="hidden" id="hidAccordionIndex" value="0" />
<script>
    $(function () {
      var activeIndex = document.getElementById("hidAccordionIndex").value;

      $("#accordion").accordion({
          heightStyle: "content",
          collapsible: true,
          navigation: true,
          active: activeIndex,
          change: function (event, ui) {
              var index = $(this).accordion("option", "active");
              $(document.getElementById("hidAccordionIndex")).val(index);
          }

      });
  } );
</script>
```

Comment: I think you need to use `$('#' + document.getElementById("hidAccordionIndex")).val(index);` or `$('#hidAccordionIndex')).val(index);` (note that `#` selector).

Comment: `document.getElementById("hidAccordionIndex")` returns HTML element and not the `id`. Change to `$("#hidAccordionIndex").val(index)` or `document.getElementById("hidAccordionIndex").value = index;`.

Comment: Right!! I was using the wrong syntax. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You have incorrect syntax there:

```
$(document.getElementById("hidAccordionIndex")).val(index);
```

`document.getElementById("hidAccordionIndex")` returns raw id value of corresponding HTML element (and there is no `id` selector to define target element's `id` attribute), hence you need to use either [jQuery id selector](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) to set its value:

```
$("#hidAccordionIndex").val(index);
```

Or using vanilla JS version:

```
document.getElementById("hidAccordionIndex").value = index;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="hidden" id="hidAccordionIndex" value="0" />

<script>
    $(function () {
        var activeIndex = parseInt($("#hidAccordionIndex").val());

      console.log(activeIndex);

      $("#accordion").accordion({
          heightStyle: "content",
          collapsible: true,
          navigation: true,
          active: activeIndex,
          activate: function (event, ui) {
              var index = $(this).accordion("option", "active");
              console.log(index);
              $("#hidAccordionIndex").val(index);
          }

      });
  } );
</script>
```